# Display custom field label on front end woocommerce product page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, textfield

I need some help. This is a two part question.

1.) How can I display a custom field's label on the front end of my site?

- I set up some custom fields in my functions.php file that show up in
  the add product page, following the instructions here:
  http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/
- They work! But how can I display the labels as well?

Here's the code I placed in my /wp-content/themes/shopifiq/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php (wasn't sure how else to get it to show in the tab)

```
<?php
    // Display custom field value
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field', true );
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_number_field', true );
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea', true );
?>
```

2.) After I get the labels to show, is there a way I can format these to not be a disorganized string of words? Is it OK to add a class to the php elements? How do I do it, like this? (added *'s)

```
      // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field', 
            ***'class'       => 'left',***
            'label'       => __( 'Manufacturer', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'Example: Herman Miller',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the manufacturer name here. Examples: Kimball, Allsteel, Herman Miller, etc.', 'woocommerce' ) 
        )
    );
```

EDIT 4/13

Hi again, I figured out how to output the form labels, but I don't think this is the best solution. It works though. But I still need to know how to add classes so I can format. I want some info in a left column and some in a right column. Thank you!

```
<?php
// Display custom field value 
    echo '<strong>Manufacturer: </strong>';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field_1', true );
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Brand: </strong>';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field', true );
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Retail Price: </strong>';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_number_field_1', true );
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Arnolds Price: </strong>';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_number_field', true );

    echo '<strong>Features: </strong>';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea_1', true );
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Additional Information: </strong>';
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea', true );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to add a class so they output in columns. Just in case anyone wants to know. I'm still open to input as to how to do this better, but for now this works.

```
<?php
// Display custom field value 
echo '<div class="left">' . '<strong>Manufacturer: </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field_1', true ) . '<br>' .
'<strong>Brand: </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field', true ) . '<br>' .
'<strong>Retail Price: </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_number_field_1', true ) . '<br>' .
'<strong>Arnolds Price: </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_number_field', true ) . '</div>';

echo '<div class="right">' . '<strong>Features: </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea_1', true ) . '<br>' . 
'<strong>Additional Information: </strong>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea', true ) . '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code (gonna post just the cell content):

```
    <td><p class="css-class"><?php $field_name = "field_55e4335cfbc8c";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);
echo $field['label'] . $field['value'];?></p></td>
```

It's based on [this](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, still trying to figure out how to display nothing in case the user doesn't complete the fields.

Hope it helps!